How to add years to year part of date field?
I have two date fields, when a user enters a date in datefield1 (dd/MM/YYY) eg 20/11/2024 I want the date in datefield2 to add 3 years to that date and show 20/11/202027. I have tried dateAdd(StartDate, "M", 36) but date add isn't a valid function

You're on the right track. Adding years is this format:
datefield1.AddYears(3) 

It's a blind add of 3 years though & has caused me some issues in the past with accuracy I needed.
Keep leap years in mind because 2/29/2024 + 3 years won't give the same date.

thank you for responding, i have tried that but get an error "Node-test expected."
../-->my:datefield1.AddYears<--(3)

Are you sure your data is a DateTime format? My presumption is you're using C#. Are you?

If you are using node.js can you try below?
var DateField1 = new Date();
var DateField2 = new Date(now.getFullYear()+3, now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

@JRrelyea
i go to the properties of the second date field and added datefield1.AddYears(3) into the function
